# Amazon s3 file download

Tags: angularjs, django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework

I am working Django REST framework / AngularJS based web application.
I am going to use amazon s3 to save all the images used in UI.
But one problem: I want Only logged-in user could access these images - so I hate direct accessing to image files on s3 bucket via url like this:

https://racerx-snap4that-media.s3.amazonaws.com/images/iPhone6White-1.png

In other word - This link should work for only authenticated user.
Is there any solution or protect policy for this? Please help me.

Comment: It's possible you are looking for CORS. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: It's something different from what I want - It's possible to direct access to image on s3, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relatively straight forward ways to accomplish this.

### Using AWS Temporary Security Credentials

When an authorised user loads your website, generate [Temporary Security Credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth) that provides the user with access to some or all of your resources within a certain bucket. During the preflight stage of your Angular application you would make a request to your API endpoint that retrieves this signature, and use it throughout your application, assuming you have a shared state somewhere.

### Serve the file through a Django view

I wouldn't recommend this, but it might be easier for you. You can simply load the image via a view like this:

```
def get(self, request):

  if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return HttpResponseForbidden()

  return HttpResponse(requests.get(your_aws_url), content_type="image/png")
```

The reason why I would not recommend this, is because you'll make the user wait for the images to download twice. Once while your server is downloading the image, and then again when the user is downloading the image. But hey, if you need a quick and dirty solution, it'll work.